# Вместо exe добавляется в автозагрузку dll в windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, автозагрузка

Есть функция добавление приложения в автозагрузку. Должно добавляться приложение в методе SetAutoRunValue(); И добавляется dll файл, с той же папки, где лежит exe файл(скомпилированный). В чём может быть проблема? Имя exe файла - r.exe , путь к нему - C:\Users\PC\source\repos\r\r\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\r.exe

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Reflection;
namespace r
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    
    private SoundPlayer sound;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAutoRunValue(true, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

   
     private bool SetAutoRunValue(bool autorun, string path)
    {
        const string name = "systems";

        string ExePath = path;
        Console.WriteLine(ExePath);
        RegistryKey reg;


        reg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");

       try
       {
            if (autorun)
            {
                reg.SetValue(name, ExePath);
            }
            else
            {
                reg.DeleteValue(name);
            }
            reg.Flush();
            reg.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

      
    }
    
        
    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\PC\source\repos\r\r\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\sv.wav");
        sound.Play();
        
    }

    
        
    


    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте поменять `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` на `Application.ExecutablePath`

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? Какую сборку запускаете, опублиеованную или нет? Просто из папки релиз? Используйте публикацию как exe файл и будет вам exe.